# Asking for proof verification or improvement regarding a simple divergence of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I am taking an Analysis 1 class in university and was recently introduced to the chapter real numbers, sequences & series and the concept of convergence and divergence. I am asked to show if a series converges or diverges and to calculate the limit if it exists. It is a rather easy example but I am not quite sure how to write down the actual mathematical proof.

The sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is given as
$$
a_n = \frac{(n+1)(n^3-1)}{(2n+1)(3n^2+1)} = \frac{n^4+n^3-n-1}{6n^3+3n^2+2n+1}.
$$
I then singled out the term $n^3$ which gives me
$$
a_n = \frac{n+1- \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^3}}{6+ \frac{3}{n} + \frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3}}
$$
Then I applied $lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n)$ and because we proofed $lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{n})=0$, I get the expression (if there is a limit - obviously not)
$$
lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n)=\frac{1}{6}lim_{n \to \infty}(n) + \frac{1}{6}
$$
So the sequence diverges. Now here my attempt to write down the proof:

> **Proof.** Let $a \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary. Select an $\varepsilon = 1$. Let $N \in \mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Now choose an $n \geq N$ such that
> $$
> \frac{n+1}{6} \geq \frac{n}{6} \geq a+1.
> $$
> Then the sequences diverges because
> $$
> \frac{n+1}{6}-a \geq 1 \gt 0 \text{ hence } \left| \frac{n+1}{6}-a \right| = \frac{n+1}{6}-a \geq 1= \varepsilon.
> $$
> $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

I am not quite sure if my mathematical argumentation is correct and if I missed something?

Comment: I think your reasoning is ok and you can stop at "so the sequence diverges". However, if you are not sure of the end of your (useless) final proof, you can replace your last line by "$\frac{n+1}6-a\ge1>0$ hence $\left|\frac{n+1}6-a\right|=\frac{n+1}6-a\ge1=\varepsilon$".

Comment: $x \geq y$ does not imply $|x - z| \geq |y - z|$ in general. So you might have to state explicitly why $| \frac{n+1}6 - a| \geq | \frac{n}6 - a|$.

Comment: "Select an ε>0, being ε=1" ? This just means "choose $\epsilon=1$"

Comment: Additionally, do you really have to prove this using the definition ? Are you not allowed to use the limit rules ? This is what they are for.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am allowed to but I am just curious how to bluntly write down the proof. I know that $lim_{n \to \infty}$ is the notation for $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \exists N \in \mathbb N \forall n \gt N: |a_n-a| \lt \varepsilon.$

Comment: To use limit rules in a context where $\lim a_n=\infty$ and $\lim b_n$ exists, one would either need a rule implying from these hypotheses that $\lim (a_n+b_n)=\infty$ or $\lim (a_nb_n) = \infty$. Such rules exist, but they're definitely different rules than the standard rule "the limit of the sum/product is the sum/product of the limit" when both limits exists, so you might or might not have such rules available. Probably the simplest other way is to use a comparison test, since when $n\ge2$ it's easy to see $a_n > \dfrac{n^4/2}{6n^3+3n^3+2n^3+1 n^3}$.

Comment: As for your given argument, it's basically a valid proof that the sequence $\dfrac{n+1}6$ diverges, but you would need to connect that to the sequence $a_n$ itself somehow.

Comment: Thank you - I also talked about it with my tutor and I think my understanding of this chapter in general is more and more coming together!